# How to remove or disable WebView header?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to remove the webview header, I've tried a number of possible solutions but to no avail.

One of my attempts:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

[image]

I'm loading the webview using this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_websitenew1);

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.domain.com");
myWebView .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: have u tried this: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening in your case is that the URL is being handled by Android which is choosing the handler for you.  This handler is the system's browser application.  What you want is for control to stay within your app.

You can do this in code as follows:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.domain.com");
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String) for details.

Comment: Updated.  It is now a bit more concise and applicable to your code.

Comment: is that  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { or  myWebView .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

Comment: still same its getting herder on top of the app...:(

Comment: can u help me to disable (not hide) scroll bars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68383/discussion-between-ejk-and-faad).